# Playing around with EFE: Ricci scalar into stress-energy density?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity

**Moving $\Lambda$ into the energy density:**

Einstein's equations with a cosmological constant $\Lambda$ (setting $c=1$), as are used for example in the solar system, are
\begin{equation}
G^\mu_{\ \ \nu} + \Lambda \delta^\mu_{\ \ \nu}= 8 \pi G_N T^\mu_{\ \ \nu}
\end{equation}
We can move the cosmological constant term to the right hand side as follows
\begin{equation}
G^\mu_{\ \ \nu} = 8 \pi G_N \left( T^\mu_{\ \ \nu} + [T_\Lambda]^\mu_{\ \ \nu} \right)
\end{equation}
where we have defined an *effective* stress-energy tensor
\begin{equation}
[T_\Lambda]^\mu_{\ \ \nu} \equiv - \frac{\Lambda}{8 \pi G_N} \delta^\mu_{\ \ \nu}
\end{equation}
The definition of energy density is $\rho = - T^0_{\ \ 0} = \frac{\Lambda}{8\pi G_N}$, and pressure is $p = T^1_{1} = T^2_2 = T^3_3 = -\frac{\Lambda}{8\pi G_N}$. From this you can see that by definition, a cosmological constant has $\rho = - p$.

This is from the answer to another question, I will link it in the comments.

**Moving $R$ into the energy density?**

I'm wondering whether it is possible and allowed and makes sense to do the same mathematical operations with the Ricci scalar and whether one can gain some insight from that?
Einstein's equations *without* a cosmological constant $\Lambda$ (setting $c=1$) are
\begin{equation}
R_{\mu\nu} -\frac{1}{2} g_{\mu\nu}R= \kappa T_{\mu\nu}
\end{equation}
Moving the $R$-term to the right hand side results in
\begin{equation}
R_{\mu\nu} = \kappa\left( T_{\mu\nu} - [T_R]_{\mu\nu} \right)
\end{equation}
where we have defined an *effective* stress-energy tensor
\begin{equation}
[T_R]_{\mu\nu} \equiv - \frac{R}{2\kappa} \delta^\mu_{\ \ \nu}
\end{equation}
The definition of energy density is $\rho = - T^0_{\ \ 0} = -\frac{R}{2\kappa}$, and pressure is $p = T^1_{1} = T^2_2 = T^3_3 = \frac{R}{2\kappa}$.

This results in a pressure - can this be interpreted as the gravitational force (direction to the centre of gravity)? Or is this nonsense, then why is it nonsense?

Comment: The equations how to bring $\Lambda$ to the right side are from the answer to this questions: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/678185/two-cosmological-constants

Comment: Moving R into the RHS is dealt with here, https://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/einstein/node10.html, and I think it answers your question.  I wish there were more "high-g, low speed" analyses out there!

Comment: What do you mean with high g low speed?

Comment: I mean the usual simplification of GR is the Newtonian approximation; low g, low speed.  That loses a lot of the interesting stuff in the process.  Consider that the low speed  part of the approximation _alone_ cuts things down to a scalar from a 4x4 matrix and allows some _real_ GR to be done (that paper I linked has some examples) by keeping the gravitational part intact.

Comment: Hm, yes, sounds interesting. Furthermore, there *isn't even* a low speed limit on galaxy scale, is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In principle, there is no gain from doing this procedure. Notice that when writing
$$G_{\mu\nu} = 8\pi T_{\mu\nu}$$
we have the huge advantage that the LHS is purely geometric, while the RHS is purely model-dependent matter. Each of the sides of the equation have completely different meanings. Nothing in the LHS is experimental (well, perhaps the dimension and signature of spacetime are), while everything on the RHS is experimental.

However, there is a trick that does something similar to what you want, but in a slightly more complicated way to get to a more interesting result. Let us begin with the field equations and take their trace. We have
\begin{align}
R_{\mu\nu} - \frac{1}{2} R g_{\mu\nu} &= 8\pi T_{\mu\nu}, \\
R_{\mu\nu}g^{\mu\nu} - \frac{1}{2} R g_{\mu\nu}g^{\mu\nu} &= 8\pi T_{\mu\nu}g^{\mu\nu}, \\
R - 2 R &= 8\pi T, \\
R &= -8\pi T,
\end{align}
where I defined $T = T_{\mu\nu}g^{\mu\nu}$ and used the fact that, in $d$-dimensions, $g_{\mu\nu}g^{\mu\nu} = d$.

Notice now that using this result we can write
\begin{align}
R_{\mu\nu} - \frac{1}{2} R g_{\mu\nu} &= 8\pi T_{\mu\nu}, \\
R_{\mu\nu} + 4\pi T g_{\mu\nu} &= 8\pi T_{\mu\nu}, \\
R_{\mu\nu} &= 8\pi \left(T_{\mu\nu} - \frac{1}{2} T g_{\mu\nu}\right),
\end{align}
which resembles the result you presented, but it is still different. Notice that, just like the original form of the Einstein Field Equations, the LHS is purely geometric, the RHS is model-dependent.

This equation can be quite useful in some situations where the stress-energy tensor is known to be traceless. For example, when all matter under consideration is electromagnetic. In this situation, we can immediately remove the trace term and get to
$$R_{\mu\nu} = 8\pi T_{\mu\nu}, \tag{$T_{\mu\nu}$ is trace-free}$$
providing a simpler version of the equations. This can be used, for example, when solving for the [Reissner–Nordström metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reissner%E2%80%93Nordstr%C3%B6m_metric). Instead of computing the Ricci scalar abstractly to solve the Einstein Equations, one can simply drop it by knowing that the stress tensor is traceless.

Comment: "there is no gain in doing so".... We will see. What we can see is: it's negative. The Ricci-scalar diminishes the stress-energy of the system. Note that the Ricci-tensor is geometric, the Ricci-scalar is only a scalar, adding or (as we see here) subtracting to the energy of the system. If we took out the whole thing, what would we gain? Zero energy, flat space. If we took out only the mass part and left in the geometric part (I know that this is not possible in reality-it's only a thought experiment) we are left with negative energy! Impressive!

Comment: By the way, thank you very much for your calculation, @Nickalas Alves, it's a great answer!

Comment: @BarrierRemoval Simply moving the Ricci scalar to the RHS doesn't mean it can be interpreted as energy, just like writing $F - ma = 0$ doesn't mean I get to interpret $-ma$ as an extra mysterious force that leads to zero total acceleration or something. The Ricci scalar is a geometric construction. It follows from the energy of the system, it is not independent from it. 

You can, however, get negative energy if there is a cosmological constant or if the stress tensor doesn't satisfy the weak energy condition, but that also doesn't mean the solution you'll get is physical.

Comment: The Ricci scalar *is* geometric. While it is a scalar, it encodes information about the curvature of the spacetime, not to mention it is defined without any reference to Physics whatsoever, and can be defined in any sufficiently differentiable manifold with a pseudo-Riemannian or Riemannian metric. It just happens that the Einstein equations relate it to the energy content on the spacetime. But that is a consequence imposed on the Ricci scalar, it is not the source of that energy